# How to configure EF6 multiple indepdendent code-first 1:1 unidirectional mappings?

Tags: c#, sql-server, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

I would like to configure two entities to have independent unidirectional 1:1 mappings using Code First Fluent API. But I am struggling to get the correct configuration (even though my schema looks right).

Models;

```
class User {
   Guid Id;
   virtual Subscription ActiveSubscription;
}

class Subscription {
   Guid Id;
   virtual User Owner;
}
```

In this relationship, `Subscription.Owner` should be `NOT NULL` but `User.ActiveSubscription` should be `NULLABLE`.

There can be many `Subscription` for the same `User`, with `0..1` of those referenced as the `User.ActiveSubscription`.

I'm using the following EntityTypeConfiguration implementations, but I am unable to `INSERT` both objects.

```
class UserMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<User> {
    HasOptional(x => x.ActiveSubscription)
        .WithOptionalDependent()
        .Map(m => m.MapKey("ActiveSubscription_Id"))
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
}

class SubscriptionMap : {
    HasRequired(x => x.Owner)
        .WithOptional()
        .Map(m => m.MapKey("Owner_Id"))
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
}
```

Deleting a `User` should `CASCADE DELETE` to `Subscription` table, though this should not be the case for the inverse relationship.

After generating a schema from this mapping, it looks correct, but I get errors on INSERT ("Unable to determine a valid ordering for dependent operations.")

Comment: Have you checked against foreign key circular dependency for all tables? Seems that either incorrect value in foreign key property or self-referencing table should be examined. Better to include code part with INSERT operation which triggered the problem.

Comment: This is just part of the schema, but there are no self-referencing tables, and this particular relationship is the only one with a circular reference of any kind. Using a DbContext (unit of work) pattern, the error occurs when adding a new (and bi-directionally related) UserAccount and Subscription object.

Comment: Removing one side of the relationship works around the issue but this is a change to an existing schema (which works fine with NHibernate) so not my preferred option.